# Tag rodapé no limite do navegador

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap-3, footer

Tenho uma tag footer na minha página HTML que chama a classe panel-footer do Bootstrap. Gostaria de deixar esse rodapé no limite do navegador aberto e conforme e não no limite do conteúdo existente na página.

```
<footer class="panel-footer">
        ....           
</footer>
```

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Coloca `position: fixed` no **CSS** neste elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.panel-footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado !